# What is the user agent of itms on ios 6.0+?

Tags: ios, ios6, app-store, user-agent

I've set up an itms-services enterprise distribution server for my company, and I've been checking the server logs to make sure that only company-issued devices are installing our company's app. We only issue the iPhone 4s and the iPad 2nd gen (all are still on ios 5.1.1) to our employees. I want to set up a script that will check the server logs for user agents after ios 6.0. Since the service that "grabs" the ipa file from the server is itms, I need to know the user agent of itms on iOS 6.0 and 6.0.1 in order to write the script.

I know that there are other ways to doing this, such as using OS X Server, but we're a startup and want to keep the cost low, and there are other limitations that make us need a script instead of some other kind of solution.

Anyways, back to the original question:

What is the user-agent of itms on ios 6.0 and above?
If unknown, is there a way I could find out?

Answer (score 1):

They are listed here http://www.enterpriseios.com/wiki/Complete_List_of_iOS_User_Agent_Strings
but you could also run http://www.wireshark.org/ on the server and sniff the agent as it comes through.